# What's the git command to distinguish a worktree folder

Tags: git

I notice a regular git repo would have `.git` as a folder whereas the worktree repo has `.git` as a file. Is this reliable?

Is there a git command to tell them apart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having `.git` as a file which points to another repository is called a gitlink, and it is not necessarily indicative of a worktree; submodules also use them, and they can be used in other, less common situations as well. Originally symlinks were used for this purpose, but that doesn't work very well on Windows, where special permissions are required for symlinks.

If you want to know whether a directory is in the main repository or a working tree, you should compare the output of `git rev-parse --git-dir` and `git rev-parse --git-common-dir`. If they are the same, then this is the main repository. If they differ, then it's a worktree.

Note that you must use a recent Git for this to work. Until (I believe) Git 2.13, `git rev-parse --git-common-dir` provided incorrect results in some cases which will affect  this check. There isn't a way to properly check on these versions other than upgrading the version of Git.